# What happens if pip uninstall fails?

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, uninstallation

What happens when pip uninstall in virtualenv fails? Is it smart enough to reinstall package or it raise an exception and leave virtualenv broken?
I'm making script which uninstall packages, run pytest and install them again. I need it for testing if dependencies are still unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think it leaves the package broken.  Pip install and pip uninstall are neither atomic nor very reliable (certainly not like, say, apt, which isn't problem-free but is much more robust).

Comment: Is there any easy way to repair that broken env? _pip install FileWithAllPackages_ will find and repair problems?

Comment: Pip isn't very smart.  The install script for a given package will PROBABLY just overwrite all of the broken stuff, mark the package as installed and exit successfully, but there's no guarantee.  And of course that assumes pip install runs at all -- if the package is still marked as installed, you'll need to find a way to force that process or forcibly mark the package as uninstalled (which is possible, I believe)